# Separate babel configuration for node.js and frontend web application is same project

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I need **Babel** not just for the web-app (build by Webpack) but also for nodejs automation utilities like `gulp`. In the general case, babel settings for web application and nodejs must not be same. The question is how to separate it.

I have not tested yet, but I suppose we could define settings for the nodejs in `.babelrc` and settings for the web application directly in webpack configuration like:

```
module.exports = {

  // ...

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader?blacklist[]=regenerator',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['env', {'modules': false}]
              ],
              plugins: [
                'syntax-dynamic-import',
                'transform-runtime'
              ]
            }
          },
          'eslint-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The question is which config webpack will give higher priority: `.babelrc` or webpack loader options (second one desired).

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration . Also check out Electron, it has separated two processes and two builds

Comment: With babel 7 it's trivial, but I see you are not using it( because of the `env` instead of `@babel/preset-env` Do you need to support an older application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer for babel 7 (latest)**

First make sure you have `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env` installed (follow install babel 7 tutorials).

Instead of .`babelrc` use [.babel.config.js](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#project-wide-configuration) in your project root directory.

Because `babel.config.js` (contrary to `package.json`)  is just javascript file, you can now use conditionals.

You can now for example set the environment variable `BABEL_ENV` which will be available in `node` as a property of the global `process` variable under `process.env.BABEL_ENV` (webpack is also run in `node` environment).

For example call `BABEL_ENV=browser npx webpack` and also call `BABEL_ENV=node some_other_command`. Now you can access `process.env.BABEL_ENV` and use logic like:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = function () {
    const isBrowser = process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'browser';

    const presets = ['shared_preset_1', 'shared_preset_2'];

    const plugins = ['shared_plugin_1', 'shared_plugin_2'];


    if (isBrowser) {
        plugins.push('YOUR PLUGIN');
    }

    if (!isBrowser) {
        // other logic
    }
}
```

As for babel 6: I'd say just try it out. If you google for that issue though, you will find a lot of confusion because `babel-loader`, that decides which babel config is used, has never documented it. Apparently there's an **undocumented** feature: `{ babelrc: false }` that prioritizes webpack set configs, but if you look it up: it's very vague!